# Creating Executable jar from CMD prompt

Tags: java, jar

I have following class files,jar and manifest in a directory

- Dot.class
- Bridge.class
- jsch.jar
- MANIFEST.MD

Manifest file contains following two lines

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Main-Class:Dot
```

command used for creating jar file

```
jar cfm dot.jar MANIFEST.MD *
```

While executing generated jar it throws error saying `no main manifest attribute`

While seeing inside the generated jar `META-INF` folder contains auto generated manifest file, it doesn't have content for my main class.

I couldn't find successful steps ,Please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below command and it works with the jar produced which i post.

```
java -cp "jsch.jar;." Dot
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue a few days ago and couldn't resolve it with the manifest file so I put the main class as a build parameter like this:

`jar cfe Main.jar MainClass *.class`

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a space after '**:**' as in

   ```
   Main-Class: Dot
   ```
2. Add a new line after the last line, in your case after **Main-Class** entry:

   ```
   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   Main-Class: Dot
   ```

The reason for 2. ist documented in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html in detail.